# SSL authentication causing issue with MVC 4 site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl, https

I've been building an ASP.Net MVC4 website for months now, and I finally added SSL to the entire site (Global filter with the `RequiredHttps` attribute). This therefore applied to my home page controller.

Since adding that, if I browse to the website, the page simply fails to load with an unknown error. If I remove the filter, the page works fine but then I can't have SSL on my entire site.

**NOTE** I have not yet acquired an SSL certificate, but I didn't think this would be a problem yet, surely it should simply ask for an exception?

Many thanks

Comment: By any chance are you behind a load balancer - we had this issue in production, load balancer doing SSL acceleration (i.e. decryption at the load balancer), when the request got to the site, it was under http.  This attribute kicked in, redirected back to the same page - repeated this until the browser decided that was too many redirects.

Comment: Ummmm... how do I find out? I use shared windows hosting for this site, I don't have access to the IIS settings myself.

Comment: No idea... Mind you - more likely the problem that you don't have a valid cert installed yet.

Comment: No, the only time you would be prompted for an exception is if you had an unverified or expired SSL cert bound to your website.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to acquire custom **self assigned SSL certificate** for this as you have mentioned which might resolve your problem.